# Remove old resources on Cloudinary

Tags: c#, .net, cloudinary, cloudinarydotnet

I'm trying to use *CloudinaryDotNet* (*Cloudinary .NET SDK*) to delete resources that has a created date older than a specific date and has a specific prefix (the beginning of a public id if I understand things correctly). I haven't found any really good way of doing this.

So far I have come up with a solution where I have to list all the resources 500 at a time, since that is the maximum of resources returned by the method `ListResources`. When I have gathered the public ids of the resources I want removed I delete them using the method `DeleteResources`.

The main problem that i have is that the versions of the list resource methods that exists are weirdly limited. `ListResources` can take an object of the type `ListResourcesParams` but this class does not contain enough properties to narrow down so I don't have to get thousands of resources with several calls for 500 resources at the time.

I thought that the solution was the method `ListResourcesByPrefix`. There is a class called `ListResourcesByPrefixParams` and it inherits from `ListResourcesParams`, but there is no version of `ListResourcesByPrefix` that takes a `ListResourcesByPrefixParams`. It takes some random parameters and creates a `ListResourcesByPrefixParams` object from them, which gives me no possibility to set propperties like `StartAt`, `Direction` or `MaxResults`.

In the end it looks like I have to choose if i want filter out resources older than a specific date or with a specific prefix, I can not combine the filtering options. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Also when `ListResourcesByPrefix` I don't seem to be able to set `MaxResults` so when using this method I have to get 10 resources at the time, which seems very weird.

I haven't been able to find any good documentation on *CloudinaryDotNet* online so this is what I discovered by reading the code and using trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i was to hasty when asking again. A bit later i realized that you can send a `ListResourcesByPrefixParams` to `ListResources` and achieve what I needed. I do however seem to need to filter the result on `CreatedAt` since that apparently is not the same thing as setting `StartAt` to the correct date and `Direction` to "desc" as I assumed.

It also seems to be necessary to set `Type` but I haven't found a list of what it can contain. The default set when using `ListResourcesByPrefix` is "upload" so that's what I used.